# Relative path changes when used in a navigation bar

Tags: php, include, absolute-path

I am using the PHP include() function within the navigation bar of my website. This navigation bar is in turn included in the Header which is included on every page of the website. The thing is when I move from page to page, the relative location of the database file changes. I have no idea how to include the absolute path of the hosted website. 
I tried to use this code:

```
$path = $_SERVER['http://mywebsite/'];
$path .= "databaseconnection.php";
include_once($path);
```

But it doesnt work. Nor does this code work:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "databaseconnection.php";
include_once($path);
```

Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using mod-rewrite/htaccess to shorten your urls?

Comment: no, nothing of the sort

Answer (score 1):

I would define a constant with the absolute path to the webroot.

config.php:

```
/* in this constant, the absolute path to the current file 
   (which is placed in the webroot) will be saved */
define('WEBROOT_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

/subpage/subpage.php

```
/* you know where the current page is, so you know the relative 
   path to the webroot and can include any file from there */
include_once("../config.php");
/* now you have the constant WEBROOT_PATH included */

...
/* on every page you have your navigation */
include ("../nav/navigation.php");
```

/nav/navigation.php:

```
/* the constant WEBROOT_PATH is also accessible here, because you
   incldued it in the parent page, so use it to find your database file- */
$path = WEBROOT_PATH."databaseconnection.php";
include_once($path);
```

Comment: Can I simply copy the code for the config file, or do i need specify some filename or path

Comment: I am not able to understand how to use this code. Where to specify my filename and path. could you suggest some resources which would help me understand this better?

Comment: I made some comments to the code above hand hope it's easier to understand now.

Comment: Thanks, but this works only when I give the path like: C:\Users\... but not when i give it as https://...